# Creating a new document that sums up a field with a specific value using aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the below from an aggregate pipeline. I want to make a doc that looks like this `{upvotes : 20, downvotes : 30}`. I would like a way to check the `vote` field and if the value is `up` add it to the `upvotes` field and the same for `down` but to the `downvotes` field. How do I make that document?

```
 { _id: 57aea6791016c0b023a71e9d,
   review:
    { _id: 57aeb0ee1015118c2b19c8b9,
      updatedAt: Fri Aug 12 2016 22:33:17 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time),
      createdAt: Fri Aug 12 2016 22:32:30 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time),
      vote: 'up',
      reviewText: 'test pleas',
      company: 57aea6791016c0b023a71e9d,
      companyName: 'comp1',
      userType: 'anon',
      user: 57aeb0dd1015118c2b19c8b8,
      statements: [Object],
      __v: 0,
      className: '',
      momented: 'a minute ago' } },
 { _id: 57aea6791016c0b023a71e9d,
   review:
    { _id: 57aeb11d3a6bd2cc24b080ad,
      updatedAt: Fri Aug 12 2016 22:33:17 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time),
      createdAt: Fri Aug 12 2016 22:33:17 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time),
      vote: 'down',
      reviewText: 'This will hopefully be good',
      company: 57aea6791016c0b023a71e9d,
      companyName: 'comp1',
      userType: 'anon',
      user: 57aeb1033a6bd2cc24b080ac,
      statements: [Object],
      __v: 0,
      className: 'thisUser',
      momented: 'a few seconds ago' } } ]
```

aggregation so far

```
Comps.aggregate([
    {"$unwind" : "$reviews"},
    {
        "$lookup":{
            "from" : "reviews",
            "localField" : "reviews",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "review"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$review" },
    {$project : {
        review:1
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the $cond operator to map "up"/"down" to 1/0 to make it easy to sum in a $group stage. I think appending something like the following to your current aggregation pipeline should work:

```
$group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    upvotes: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["up", "$review.vote"]}, 1, 0]}},
    downvotes: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["down", "$review.vote"]}, 1, 0]}}
}
```

Here is the documentation on the [$cond expression operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/).